# XlsxWriter button caption using formula

Tags: python, excel, xlsxwriter

Is there any way to give a button a caption using a formula in xlsxwriter, to get a cell value as caption for example ?

```
worksheet3.insert_button(row_sheet3, col3, {'macro': 'PMF',
                                            'caption': '=Général!A1'})
```

I tried like this but it doesn't work..